# Flash not displaying after clearing session

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to flash a message after redirecting a user back to the log in page if a username or password is not filled out. However I noticed the flash is not displayed when I have a statement to clear the session. When i remove `session.clear()`, the flash shows on the redirected page. This signals, that Flask stores the flash in sessions. What is the best way to display the flash in this case?

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            flash("Must provide username", "danger")
            return redirect("/login")

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            flash("Must provide password", "danger")
            return redirect("/login")
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: Do you need to handle this in flask? Cant you just make the username field required so it doesnt get submitted if empty?

Comment: @Ahmet I have the fields set as required, but i believe anyone can by pass this by going into the html source code with browsers like chrome, so a backend validation should still be necessary.